# How can I run an application in the background so a user can not stop it

Tags: 16.04, users

I've set up a computer for my kids to do homework on (Ubuntu 16.04) and am currently using team viewer to occasionally take a look at what they are doing from work, mobile, my desk, wherever. Is there a way to prevent their user accounts from being able to close the team viewer application. For right now they haven't figured out what it is for and are just minimizing it, but we all know that wont last long.

Only instructions I've been able to find relate to the window itself, which I do not mind if they minimize/close. I only care that team viewer runs in the background without them being able to shut it down. I'd even love it if the window never came up to begin with and it just ran in the background.

Comment: How would you know the TV password? You might look at just running a VNC server like **vino**. Check `Desktop Sharing` in the dash. It's already there. Cheers, Al

Comment: I cant test at the moment but you can set the pwd via the command line and run the program woth "&" at the end they could still kill the pid but thats much more advanced!